# SDK 2: Example of a settings dialog

Tags: javascript, extjs, rally

Do you have an example posted of a SDK 2 app that adds an entry to its "Gear" menu and allows the user to save settings to a preference object via a dialog window?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is that right now that is not possible.

We are trying to figure out the best way to allow users to interact with setting from inside of a custom App. Since each App is sandboxed inside of an IFrame no App code can interact with the gear menu (since it is outside of your frame).

In the future we are looking into ways to make custom Apps and Rally Apps interact with Settings in a unified way.

If you are looking to store settings you can check into the documentation for the [App](https://rally1.rallydev.com/apps/2.0p2/doc/#!/api/Rally.app.App) object. In the 2.0p2 version of the SDK we added some functionality to help you manage settings on your Apps. 
Right now all custom Apps will have to provide their own interface to access settings.

Comment: This seems pretty good and could get me most of the way there, but I'm having some trouble using it.  At the top of my launch() function, I've added: console.log('settings', this.settings); this.updateSettings({myKey: 'is a test'});  But on refresh, settings do not seem to change, and I'm not sure how to interact with the settings object (is there doc?).  Also, what is the scope of settings?  For a particular user of an app?  Thanks!!!

Comment: Right now the settings are tied to instance of the App only. So if that App is shared on a dashboard all the users will have the same settings. If you have two of the same App each will have different settings.

Comment: Also the settings will not work in the App is not hosted inside Rally. So if you are working from local files it can be a pain to test it.

Answer (score 2):

I ended up using the ExtJS CookieProvider to save my app's state. By using cookies the settings are per user, and I also made them per-project. My code within the App class looks like this:

```
...
sessionKey: function() {
  return (this.getContext().get('appID') || 'MyAppName') + ':' + this.getContext().getProject()._ref;
},

session: function() {
  if (!this.state)
    this.state = Ext.state.Manager.get(this.sessionKey()) || {};

  return this.state;
},

saveSession: function(newState) {
  var session = this.session();
  Ext.apply(session, newState);
  Ext.state.Manager.set(this.sessionKey(), session);
},

launch: function() {
   Ext.state.Manager.setProvider(Ext.create('Ext.state.CookieProvider'));
   ...
```

To use it, just call this.session() to get the state, and saveSession() to merge the state back in. Works great!

It will even work in dev mode. Note that Chrome (and other browsers?) will not save cookies in file:// mode unless you [tell it to](http://wolfslittlestore.be/2012/08/cookies-on-local-files-in-chrome/).