# SDK 2: How to use settings

Tags: rally

I have been unable to get SDK 2 settings to work using this.settings and this.updateSettings() (and I realize this needs to be run on Rally right now).

I presume when I run this a second time in an app, I should be able to see the setting made in the previous run, but settings itself is a fairly uninteresting object.  And in general, where is the method that allows you to get a setting that you have saved previously?

```
    console.log('settings object', this.settings);
    this.updateSettings({myKey: 'is a test'});
```

I saw some of the previous postings on settings, one which talked about a getSetting() method, but if this exists, I'm not sure which object it is attached to, or where to find documentation on it.

Answer (score 0):

Someone else was attempting to do something similar. Here is their wisdom.

[Is there an example of setting and retrieving settings from a Rally SDK 2 app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11680816/is-there-an-example-of-setting-and-retrieving-settings-from-a-rally-sdk-2-app)

Comment: Yes, I saw that but it did not seem to make a difference-- I still can't seem to get settings to save.